# StackExchange API Java SDK

Tags: library, api, api-v2, api-v2.2, java

This project aims to provide a Java wrapper to the Stack Exchange API.

- SDK supports Stack Exchange API V2.2

### Getting Started

There are two interfaces to the library.

- Query Interface
- Facade Interface

### Feature

- **Asynchronous API** Examples of using the API asynchronously are described in Asynchronous API.
- **Advanced Usage** Advanced usage like changing API providers or paging through the results are described in Advanced Usage.
- **Spring Configuration** If you plan to use the library in conjunction with Spring framework, this brief tutorial will guide you. Spring Configuration
- **Query API** Query API provides a Builder like syntax to the StackOverflow? API.There are similar Query interfaces for Answers, Comments, Timelines, Badges etc.
- **Switch Site** Fetching records from different site are described here.
- **Advance Search** Advance search feature available in SDK.

### Code Snippet

```
StackExchangeApiQueryFactory queryFactory = StackExchangeApiQueryFactory
        .newInstance("applicationKey", 
        StackExchangeSite.STACK_OVERFLOW);


// Get all questions.
String filter = "default";
Paging paging = new Paging(1, 100);
PagedList<Question> questions = queryFactory.newQuestionApiQuery()
     .withPaging(paging).withFilter(filter)
     .withSort(Question.SortOrder.MOST_HOT)
     .withTags(tag).list();

//Get questions by answer ids. 
long answerId = 21859130; 
PagedList<Question> question3s =
     queryFactory.newQuestionApiQuery()
     .withPaging(paging).withFilter(filter)
     .withSort(Question.SortOrder.MOST_RECENTLY_CREATED)
     .withTags(tag).withAnswerIds(answerId).listQuestionsByAnswer();
```

### Code

Source code is available under my [sanjivsingh/stackoverflow-java-sdk](https://github.com/sanjivsingh/stackoverflow-java-sdk) repository.

### Issues

Please feel free to raise bugs/issues at [GitHub issues](https://github.com/sanjivsingh/stackoverflow-java-sdk/issues)

Or You can contact me here [sanjiv.singh](https://stackapps.com/users/22733/sanjiv)

Answer (score 3):

stackoverflow-java-sdk artifacts have been upload to Maven Central.

Now, You simply add maven dependency in your project POM

**Dependency**

```
  <dependency>   
   <groupId>com.googlecode.stackexchange</groupId>   
   <artifactId>stackoverflow-java-sdk-release</artifactId>   
   <version>2.2.0</version>   
  </dependency>
```

**Repository**

```
  <repository>            
   <id>oss.sonatype</id>            
   <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/<url>     
   <releases>                 
     <enabled>true</enabled>              
   </releases>              
  </repository>
```

and start experimenting with SDK.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the right repository config would be like:

```
<repository>
    <id>oss.sonatype</id>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
</repository>
```